# Python datetime corruption in panda.concat

Tags: python, pandas

When invoking panda.concat on dataframes containing datetime objects occasionally one of the objects advances an hour in time due to 'some' interaction with a datetime on another row.

```
from dateutil import parser
import pytz
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
```

A helper function...

```
def to_ldn(dt):
    assumed_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
    local_dt = assumed_timezone.normalize(assumed_timezone.localize(parser.parse(dt)))
    return local_dt.astimezone(assumed_timezone)
```

A dataframe containing a single row, the effect only shows up when concatenating more than one dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':pd.Series([to_ldn('2016-01-06 14:48:03')]), 'Id':pd.Series(['ID1'])})
```

A dataframe containing two rows.  Note that the first datetime is within the GMT+1 date range of the timezone Europe/London.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':pd.Series([to_ldn('2016-06-06 14:48:03'),
                                      to_ldn('2016-01-06 14:48:03')]), 
                'Id':pd.Series(['ID2','ID3'])})
```

Now concat them...

```
print pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

- DateTime   Id
- 0 2016-01-06 14:48:03+00:00  ID1
- 0 2016-06-06 14:48:03+01:00  ID2
- 1 2016-01-06 **15:48:03+00:00**  ID3

Notice that the final datetime (corresponding to ID3) has jumped one hour forward. If the date of the timestamp corresponding to ID2 is NOT in the period where the Europe/London timezone corresponds to GMT+1 then this does NOT occur.

This occurs in python 2.7.12 (Anaconda 4.2.0) and python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.2.0)

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in Anaconda 4.3 running on python 2.7.13.